# Multi-Series timeline: plot the lines one by one

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Here is the jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/zdmnus3m/

I am able to draw/plot Multi-Series timeline. Here is my codebase for this

```
var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
          .data(citiesdata)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "city");

        city.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return line(d.values);
          })
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return color(d.name);
          });

        city.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) {
            return {
              name: d.name,
              value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
            };
          })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
          })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
          });
```

So this piece of code plotting all timelines at once, I want to add animation and plot one after another. How is it possible. If `transition` property with `duration` will work. I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have added `transition` and `duration` seems to be animation part is working.But for some reason timelines are overlapping. https://jsfiddle.net/vx618wsn/

Comment: Fixed that overlapping issue , now each timeline is getting plotted with proper animation , but still not happening one after another .  https://jsfiddle.net/854g1ezx/

Comment: I would suggest, something like

    `plottimelines(svg,[cities[0]]);`
    `plottimelines(svg,[cities[1]]);`

But that only plots the first one, also tried putting it in plottimelines callback but still only plots the first one

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your calculation of `getTotalLength` is wrong, you're calculating the length of the first path only. It should be:

```
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", function(){
    return this.getTotalLength();
})
```

That being fixed, the solution is a simple `delay` with the node's index:

```
.delay(function(_,i){
    return 2000 * i;
})
```

Here is your code with those 2 changes:

```js
 var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin Bangalore\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2 32.6\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7 43.9\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4 55.0\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0 54.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4 23.7\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0 56.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3 98.0\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9 45.0\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8 65.0\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7 65.0\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3 45.0\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3 34.5\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6 56.9\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6 12.0\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0 87.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6 77.3\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1 34.8\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0 56.7\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6 29.9\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4 34.9\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3 56.0\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4 66.0\n";

 var margin = {
     top: 20,
     right: 80,
     bottom: 30,
     left: 50
   },
   width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

 var x = d3.time.scale()
   .range([0, width]);

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
   .range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.category10();

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x)
   .orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y)
   .orient("left");

 var line = d3.svg.line()
   .interpolate("basis")
   .x(function(d) {
     return x(d.date);
   })
   .y(function(d) {
     return y(d.temperature);
   });



 var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

 color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
   return key !== "date";
 }));

 data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 });

 var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
   return {
     name: name,
     values: data.map(function(d) {
       return {
         date: d.date,
         temperature: +d[name]
       };
     })
   };
 });

 var newCities = cities

 var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .selectAll('g')
   .data(newCities)
   .enter()
   .append('g')
   .attr('class', 'legend');

 legend.append('rect')
   .attr('x', width - 20)
   .attr('y', function(d, i) {
     return i * 20;
   })
   .attr('width', 10)
   .attr('height', 10)
   .style('fill', function(d) {
     return color(d.name);
   });

 legend.append('text')
   .attr("id", function(d) {
     return d.name.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "").replace(/ /g, '');
   })
   .attr('x', width - 8)
   .attr('y', function(d, i) {
     return (i * 20) + 9;
   })
   .text(function(d) {
     return d.name;
   })
   .attr("fill", "black")
   .style("cursor", "pointer")
   .on("click", function(d) {
     drawBoxes(this.id);
   });



 var svg = d3.select("#mysvg").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 plottimelines(svg, cities)

 function plottimelines(svg, citiesdata) {



   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
     return d.date;
   }));

   y.domain([
     d3.min(citiesdata, function(c) {
       return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
         return v.temperature;
       });
     }),
     d3.max(citiesdata, function(c) {
       return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
         return v.temperature;
       });
     })
   ]);

   //for(var i=0;i<citiesdata.length;i++){
   var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
     .data(citiesdata)
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "city");

   var path = city.append("path")
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", function(d) {
       return line(d.values);
     })
     .style("stroke", function(d) {
       return color(d.name);
     });

   path.attr("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
     .attr("stroke-dashoffset", function() {
       return this.getTotalLength();
     })
     .transition()
     .duration(2000)
     .delay(function(_, i) {
       return 2000 * i;
     })
     .ease("linear")
     .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

   city.append("text")
     .datum(function(d) {
       return {
         name: d.name,
         value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
       };
     })
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
       return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
     })
     .attr("x", 3)
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .text(function(d) {
       return d.name;
     });
   city.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);

   city.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Temperature (ºF)");

   //}
   function tweenDash() {
     var l = this.getTotalLength()
     return (l + " " + l);
   }


   var mouseG = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

   mouseG.append("path") // this is the black vertical line to follow mouse
     .attr("class", "mouse-line")
     .style("stroke", "black")
     .style("stroke-width", "1px")
     .style("opacity", "0");

   var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

   var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
     .data(citiesdata)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

   mousePerLine.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 7)
     .style("stroke", function(d) {
       return color(d.name);
     })
     .style("fill", "none")
     .style("stroke-width", "1px")
     .style("opacity", "0");

   mousePerLine.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

   mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
     .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
     .attr('height', height)
     .attr('fill', 'none')
     .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
     .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
       d3.select(".mouse-line")
         .style("opacity", "0");
       d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
         .style("opacity", "0");
       d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
         .style("opacity", "0");
     })
     .on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
       d3.select(".mouse-line")
         .style("opacity", "1");
       d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
         .style("opacity", "1");
       d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
         .style("opacity", "1");
     })
     .on('mousemove', function() { // mouse moving over canvas
       var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
       d3.select(".mouse-line")
         .attr("d", function() {
           var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
           d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
           return d;
         });

       d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
         .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
           console.log(width / mouse[0])
           var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
             bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
               return d.date;
             }).right;
           idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

           var beginning = 0,
             end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
             target = null;

           while (true) {
             target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
             pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
             if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
               break;
             }
             if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
             else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
             else break; //position found
           }

           d3.select(this).select('text')
             .text(y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));

           return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
         });
     });

 }



 function drawBoxes(id) {



   var color_ = d3.select('#' + id).attr("fill");
   console.log(color_)
   if (color_ == 'black') {
     d3.select('#' + id).attr("fill", "#FFFAFA");
   } else {
     d3.select('#' + id).attr("fill", "black");
   }

   var results = newCities.filter(function(d) {
     var colorText = d3.select('#' + d.name.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "").replace(/ /g, '')).attr("fill");
     if (colorText == 'black') {
       return {
         name: d.name,
         values: data.map(function(d) {
           return {
             date: d.date,
             temperature: +d[name]
           };
         })
       };
     }
   });
   var myNode = document.getElementById("mysvg");
   while (myNode.firstChild) {
     myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
   }
   //console.log(results)
   //console.log([results[0]])
   var svg = d3.select("#mysvg").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   //for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
   plottimelines(svg, results)
   //}

 }
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
<div id="mysvg"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
```